# Scaling row-wise with MinMaxScaler from Sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, normalization, train-test-split

By default, scalers from Sklearn work column-wise. But i need my data to be scaled line-wise, so i did the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

# %% Generating sample data

x = np.array([[-1, 4, 2], [-0.5, 8, 9], [3, 2, 3]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])

#%% Train/Test split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train.T).T # scaling line-wise
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test) <-------- Error here
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: X has 3 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 2 features as input.
```

I don't understand whats wrong here. Why it says it is expecting 2 features, when all my X (x, x_train and x_test) has 3 features? How can i fix this?

Comment: When you write x_train.T, you fit MinMaxScaler on shape=(3,2) and you want to transform MinMaxScaler on x_test with shape shape=(1,3), So you got an error.

Comment: @I'mahdi ooh i understand the error now. Any ideas in how to fix this? Is there any other approach to normalize my data line-wise without using the `.T` data?

Comment: You can solve with this : `x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)` and `x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)`, do you want  this?

Comment: @I'mahdi that does not work for me. Because as i said, the default mode of Sklearn scalers are column-wise. And i need my scaling to be performed row-wise. Thats why i used `scaler.fit_transform(x_train.T).T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StandardScaler` is stateful: when you fit it, it calculates and saves the columns' means and standard deviations; when transforming (train *or* test sets), it uses those saved statistics. Your transpose trick doesn't work with that: each *row* has saved statistics, and then your test set doesn't have the same rows, so transform cannot work correctly (throwing an error if different number of rows, or silently mis-scaling if the same number of rows).

What you want *isn't* stateful: test sets should be transformed completely independently of the training set. Indeed, every row should be transformed independently of each other. So you could just do this kind of transformation before splitting, or using `fit_transform` on the test set('s transpose).

For l2 normalization of rows, there's a builtin for this: `Normalizer` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html)).  I don't think there's an analogue for min-max normalization, but I think you could write a `FunctionTransformer` to do it.

Comment: Are you sure we should do a transformation before splitting the data? I've read here in SO (and other SX sites and all over the web) that doing that would lead to data leakage. Also, the test set should not be transformed completely independently of the training set (in fact, you use the same scaler applied to the train set, in the test set).

Comment: It's not leakage in this case because you are transforming the _rows_ independently; the test set's transformation doesn't depend at all on the training set's transformation.  (You could in this case also `fit_transform` the transposed test set.)  But yes, to be clearer about what's going on (and to allow pipelining the transform), using `Normalizer` is best.  But you'll see the exact same results.

Comment: @Murilo oh, the other answer called my attention to your desire for min-max scaling rather than l2 scaling. I don't think there's a builtin like `Normalizer` for that. You could make one out of a `FunctionTransformer`, I think.

Comment: Oh, i guess i get it now when you say that the rows are being independently transformed. But just to be sure, in this case (i.e, `MinMaxScaler`), it is ok to use the same `scaler = MinMaxScaler()` i used in `fit_transform(x_train.T).T` to `fit_transform(x_test.T).T` ?

Comment: Right, because the statistics being learned are per row, and you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Really interesting, i haven't thought on that before you said. I'll accept this as answer, since it solved my problem. If you wish, you can also add that information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do.  I can think of a scenario where this would be useful.    Normally, `MinMaxScaler` would scale each `x`, `y`, and `z` with respect to other observations of that feature.  That's the "series" scaling.  Now imagine that instead, you wanted to map each point constrained by `x+y+z = 1`.  I think this is what OP is asking for.  I have done this in the past, I will describe how I did it.

You need to treat your individual observations as a column multi-index and treat it like a higher-dimensional feature.  Then, you need to build a pipeline within which the observations are transformed from column-wise to row wise, post which you do the min/max scaling. This gets you to x+y+z=1, but you still need to get back to the original shape of the data, for which you will need to track the index of each observation.  Within the pipeline, you'll need to use something like a `DataframeFunctionTransformer` which I have seen on the interwebs, reproducing it below. This way you can use pandas functions to shape the data and merge back in with the indices.

```
class DataframeFunctionTransformer():                                                                                                                                       
    def __init__(self, func):                                                                                                                                               
        self.func = func                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                            
    def transform(self, input_df, **transform_params):                                                                                                                      
        return self.func(input_df)                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                            
    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):                                                                                                                                 
        return self
```

Regarding the statefulness of `MinMaxScaler`, I think in a scenario such as this, the state of `MinMaxScaler` doesn't get used, it is purely acting as a transformer that maps these points to a different space meeting the constraint that `x`, `y`, and `z` are scaled such that they add up to 1.

@Murilo hope this gets you started with a solution.  Must be an interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been struggling with the same issue, so have put together a class that:

1. uses a new transformer instance for each call to avoid the issue with state
2. optionally transposes the input and output data to use a feature-wise transformers row-wise instead

```py
class StatelessTransformer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, transformer_class: TransformerMixin, sample_wise: bool = True):
        """
        Create a stateless transformer from a statefull transformer class.

        By default, `transform` transposes input and output data to apply feature-wise transformers to samples (rows).
        Allows use of feature-wise, stateful transformers in an sklearn `Pipeline`.

        Examples
        --------

        >>> import numpy as np
        >>> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
        >>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler
        >>> pipeline = Pipeline([("sample_scaler", StatelessTransformer(MaxAbsScaler))])
        >>> X = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
        >>> pipeline.transform(X)
        array([[0. , 0.5, 1. ],
               [0.6, 0.8, 1. ]])

        >>> pipeline = Pipeline([("sample_scaler", StatelessTransformer(MaxAbsScaler, sample_wise=False))])
        >>> pipeline.transform(X)
        array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.4 ],
               [1.  , 1.  , 1.  ]])
        """
        self.transformer_class = transformer_class
        self.sample_wise = sample_wise

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        """Stateless, so no fit operation."""
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        """
        Calls `.fit_transform` from a new instance of the stateful transformer class, so that no state is held.
        Note that default fit parameters are used.
        """
        if self.sample_wise:
            return self.transformer_class().fit_transform(X.T).T
        return self.transformer_class().fit_transform(X)
```